# I made the Anchor tag as button and it is not working

Tags: php, css, frontend

Im trying to make the anchor tag as button and trying to add some css on it but it is not clickable
Here is my html code.
I'm following a youtube tutorial, I followed the video 100% but mine is not working, Im sorry im just new in web developing thankyou for the help.

```html
    <body>
      <!-- Welcome Page -->
      <section id="ulambg"> 
        <div class="ulambg container">
          <div>
            <h1>Eatwell</h1>
            <a href="#" type="button" class="btnulam">Ready to Eat</a>
            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ready to Cook</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    
      <!-- End Welcom Page -->
```

And this is the css I used in the program, is it because of the Java? I read some forum that says some java function wont work if you disabled your java on your machine.

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap');
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif ;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .container { 
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
     }
     
    
    /*Welcome Page Section Ulambg*/
    #ulambg { 
        background-image: url(./img/bg.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top center;
        position: relative;
     }
     #ulambg::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: .5;
     }
    
     #ulambg h1 {
        color: white;
        width: fit-content;
        font-size: 4rem;
        position: relative;
    
     }
    
     #ulambg .btnulam {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        color: blue;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .1rem;
        margin-top: 30px;
        transition: .3s ease;
        transition-property: background-color;
     }
    
     #ulambg .btnulam:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
     }
    
    
    /*Welcome Page Sectio Ulambg*/
```

Comment: you have not given any href link to your anchor tag, then how will it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `z-index: -1` in `#ulambg::after`, it's background, should not cover the page.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/jfw10973/pen/poEbVRo?editors=1100)

Answer (score -1):

if i understand u correct, u mean <a href="#".. <- Anchor tag isnt clickable?
If yes u need to give it a name like <a href="#goHere".. and this means the link points to an id somewhere on the page ( for example to: <img id="goHere" src="/img/pic.gif"...

I'm new to the stuff myself but hopefully i could help in any way :)